# How to find the confidence interval of a parameter estimator from an inverse Gaussian distribution?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, confidence-interval, parameter-estimation

This is homework!

I have $n$ samples $x_1\dots x_n$ which are i.i.d taken from an Inverse Gaussian distribution $X\sim IG(\mu, \lambda)$.

$f_X(x) = \sqrt{\frac{\lambda}{2\pi x^3}}\exp\bigr({\frac{-\lambda(x-\mu)^2}{2\mu^2x}}\bigl),\space \space \space x \gt 0$

I know that the MLE estimator for $\lambda$ is 
 $\hat\lambda = \frac{n}{\sum_i^n(\frac{1}{X_i}-\frac{1}{\bar X})}$.

Using the fact that $\frac{n\lambda}{\hat\lambda}\sim\chi_{n-1}^2$, I need to find the $100(1-\alpha)\text{%}$ confidence interval for $\lambda$.

What I did:

I know that $\space\space L, U = \hat\lambda \space\pm\space c\frac{SD(\hat\lambda)}{\sqrt{n}}$ 
 and since that the distribution is not normal and n is unknown, I should probably use $t_{29}(c) = 1 - \frac{\alpha}{2}$, to find c. 
 I don't know the sample size, so the final answer should include an $n$.
I don't know how to find the standard deviation of $\hat\lambda$.

If also possible, can you show me how would you find the same CI in R.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How large is $n$? If $n$ is sufficient large you can approximate a $\chi^2_{n-1}$ distribution with a $\mathcal{N}\big(n-1,2(n-1)\big)$ distribution.

Comment: If $n$ is large then $\frac{\frac{n \lambda}{\hat{\lambda}}-n+1}{\sqrt{2(n-1)}}$ is approximately $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ and $$-z_{\alpha/2}<\frac{\frac{n \lambda}{\hat{\lambda}}-n+1}{\sqrt{2(n-1)}}<z_{\alpha/2} $$is equivalent to saying that $$\frac{\hat{\lambda}}{n}\Bigg[n-1-z_{\alpha/2}\sqrt{2(n-1)}\Bigg]<\lambda < \frac{\hat{\lambda}}{n}\Bigg[n-1+z_{\alpha/2}\sqrt{2(n-1)}\Bigg]$$ giving you a confidence interval.

Comment: Also, if you want to find the variance of $\hat{\lambda}$ you could first set $\hat{l}=\frac{n\lambda}{\hat{\lambda}}\sim \chi^2_{n-1}$ and notice how $$V(\hat{\lambda})=E\Big(\hat{\lambda}^2\Big)-\Big(E\big(\hat{\lambda}\big)\Big)^2=n^2 \lambda^2\bigg[E\Big(\hat{l}^{-2}\Big)-\Big(E\big(\hat{l}^{-1}\big)\Big)^2\bigg]$$ Using LOTUS: $$E\Big(\hat{l}^{-2}\Big)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^2}f_{\hat{l}}(x)dx$$ $$E\Big(\hat{l}^{-1}\Big)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x}f_{\hat{l}}(x)dx$$ Here $f_{\hat{l}}$ is the pdf for a $\chi^2_{n-1}$ random variable.

Comment: There exists $a,b$ such that $P(a<n\lambda/\hat\lambda<b)=1-\alpha$.